# Topology of the automorphic quotient

Tags: product-space, adeles

The MO question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331549/compactness-of-the-automorphic-quotient-and-genericity made me realise that I don't really understand the topology on the adèlic points of an algebraic group $G$.  Indeed, the way I realised this is by making the wrong comment https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331549/compactness-of-the-automorphic-quotient-and-genericity#comment826950_331549.  To save your following the link, the question is about consequences of compactness of $G(F)\backslash G(\mathbb A)$.  Now I thought that, for each place $v$,

1. the group $G(F_v)$ is a closed subgroup of $G(\mathbb A)$; and,
2. since $G(F)$ is embedded diagonally in $G(\mathbb A)$, it intersects $G(F_v)$ trivially; so
3. $G(F_v)$ sits as a closed subset of $G(F)\backslash G(\mathbb A)$.

Since further discussion (for example, paulgarrett's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/331628)) showed that the conclusion is wrong, obviously one of the steps is wrong—but I'm embarrassed to say I don't know which one.  Is it the first?  If so, is there any easier way to see why than "because there's a definition of closed set that $G(F_v)$ doesn't satisfy"?

Comment: Why is step 3 true? Is the quotient map closed?

Comment: @rj7k8, well, one (or more) of the steps is false; maybe that's the one!